# XMLHttpRequest interrupts typing in a text field

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have written a small chat application using XMLHttpRequest.
Calling these 3 lines will interrupt the typing.

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.com/chat?action=getLatestEntries&latestID="+latestID, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

If a user types in something into the text field, the XMLHttpRequest call will interrupt the typing for 1 or 2 seconds.

Any idea how I can fix this?

The full code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var latestID = 0; // global
//This function will display the messages
function showmessages(){
   //Send an XMLHttpRequest 
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.com/chat?action=getLatestEntries&latestID="+latestID, false);
      xmlhttp.send(null);
   }
   else{
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.com/chat?action=getLatestEntries&latestID="+latestID, false);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }   
   //Replace the content of the messages with the response from the .py file
   elem_messages = document.getElementById("messages");
   if (elem_messages) {
     elem_messages.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }

   // put scrollbar to bottom   
   elem_chat = document.getElementById("chat");
   if (elem_chat) {   
     elem_chat.scrollTop = document.getElementById("scroll_down").offsetTop + 5000;        
   } 
   //Repeat the function each 5 seconds
   setTimeout('showmessages()',5000);
}
//Start the showmessages() function
showmessages();
//This function will submit the message
</script>


<div id="chat" style="height: 450px; overflow: auto; width: 700px;">
    <div id="messages"></div>    
    <span id="scroll_down" />      
</div>

<div id="write">
    <form name="chatform" id="chatform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="send();return false"
          style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <p>Message:</p>
        <input type="text" id="message" size="90" /><br/>
        <div style="margin-top:6px"><input type="button" value="Send" onClick="send();" /></div>        
    </form>
</div>
```

Note: The send() function is not listed here to keep the posting small and clean.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using a synchronous request which locks up the browser. You would need to change it to an asynchronous request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How do I convert this to an asynchronous request?

Comment: use onreadystatechange and change the false to true on the open() method.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work:  `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
          xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.com/chat?action=getLatestEntries&latestID="+latestID, true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);
      }`

Comment: the <div> container "messages" is empty and no chat messages are displayed.

Comment: I think, I got it. `//Send an XMLHttpRequest 
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.com/chat/?action=getLatestEntries&latestID="+latestID, true);
  xmlhttp.onload = function (e) {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            //Replace the content of the messages with the response from the .py file
            elem_messages.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
  }
xmlhttp.send(null); `